# Avatar rails generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rubygems, gravatar

I am trying to find some `rails gem` or any API delivering some random (non figurative) picture for avatar users, as the one that `SO` uses.

I tried `gravatar` but when I create some random hash and that I call the api via `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}`, I always get the same default image (independently of the hash)

So perhaps I misunderstood the purpose of gravatar, so is there any API or `rails gem` offering this service ?

Comment: https://github.com/victorgama/identicon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `?d=identicon` to your query.
[Docs here](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/)